# React-native error. fatal error: 'React/RCTUtils.h' file not found

Tags: react-native

After launching a react-native application on a new device, an error occurs:

```
 npx react-native run-ios

Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening Erta.xcworkspace.
/Users/thelookin/work/erta/app_source/erta_mobile_app/node_modules/react-native-device-info/ios/RNDeviceInfo/RNDeviceInfo.m:13:9: fatal error: 'React/RCTUtils.h' file not found
#import <React/RCTUtils.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Before that, all that was necessary was done:

```
npm install
pod install
```

Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'Erta' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_native_modules!

  # Pods for Erta

  target 'ErtaTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```